# PHP Get date with day of the week

Tags: php

How can I get the full name of the day of the week in PHP like `Monday` or `Friday`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```php
echo date('D, d M Y h:i:s');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: 'N' is the numeric representation of the day (1-7), it should be 'D' instead

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz Yep 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)